# if LT IE 8 alert message cookie

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, if-statement, alert, onload

I've got an IF/Then alert message that pops up for internet explorer users warning them that the website is not completely compatible in their browser (HTML5, etc). I've built the warning into every page, thinking that it would automatically launch on the first page visited (whichever it is) and then would be ignored for the rest of the pages if it was clicked closed.

wrong!

I've been suggested making a cookie to check to see if the alert has been pressed while visiting the site. I understand the concept, but it's way above my head. Any help?

Thank you!

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]><script type="text/javascript">function message(){alert("We're sorry. Your browser is not able to properly display some features of this website. Please upgrade or use a newer browser. Click OK to view this website anyway.");}</script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body  onload="message()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a cookie that would say if the person has received the message that you do not show the message again.

http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp